# How do i put a icon to jLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

By default it has an image with the path `/img/profileicon/29.png`
but then from the main I want to change it, but for some reason instead of changing it disappears.

The code:

```
int iconId = summoner.getProfileIconId();
        ImageIcon img = new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/img/profileicon/"+iconId+".png");
        profileIconImg.setIcon(img);
```

Comment: Start by using `ImageIO.read` over `ImageIcon`, if something is going wrong, `ImageIO` will throw a `IOException`

Comment: Also, note that `/img/profileicon...` points to the `img` folder in the ROOT (`/`) of the drive. If you want to use a relative path, then you have to use `"img/profileicon/"+iconId+".png"` (Note the missing `/` at the beginning).

Comment: @KartikSoneji  when I put an image manually in the code it uses the path /img/profileicon/ so it has to be right

Comment: @MadProgrammer How do I use it?

Comment: @JorgeMontejo what do you mean be "manually"?

Comment: You can also check by doing `ls /img/profileicon`. If you see `.png` files then the path is correct.

Comment: @KartikSoneji in netBeans right click in the jlabel>properties>icon

Comment: Interesting. Did you try `ls /img/profileicon` in the terminal?

Comment: @KartikSoneji im on windows ,so i cant do that, look the tree of the folders of src: https://ibb.co/YLZzjhH

Comment: Can you try `"img/profileicon/"+iconId+".png"`?

Comment: @KartikSoneji yes, i try it and nothing

Comment: OK, can you print out the path to confirm that it is correct and the photo exists?

Comment: @KartikSoneji https://ibb.co/QFHCqGB

Comment: Let us try @MadProgrammer 's suggestion: `new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/img/profileicon/"+iconId+".png")))` should throw an error if anything is wrong.

Comment: @KartikSoneji yes, it works, but dont work when i build the jar file :(

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) which shows how to load the file as a resource so the code will also work when using a jar file.

Comment: @camickr I've read it but I still don't know how to do it :(

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to do it. You copy the code then compile and test the code. How is it any different if I type the code here and you copy the code?

Comment: @camickr finaly i do it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to use this code, making use of class.getResource

```
URL iconUrl = EuwGG.class.getResource("/img/profileicon/"+profileIconId+".png");
    Image profileImage = ImageIO.read(iconUrl);
    ImageIcon profileIcon = new ImageIcon(profileImage);
    Image i = profileIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(125, 125, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    profileIcon = new ImageIcon(i);
    profileIconImg.setIcon(profileIcon);
```